# Pop up notification when having missed calls

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, calllog

I am working on an android app.

I need to popup a message every time I have missed called.

I am retrieving missed calls using `CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI`.

I need some advices. How to do this?

Comment: i think you've missed the boat a bit - there's at least 50 apps out there already that do this http://androidapp.lisisoft.com/android-apps/missed-call-popup.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implement brodcst receiver and for that use I suppose you could use PhoneStateListener to listen for call state change from CALL_STATE_RINGING to CALL_STATE_IDLE which indicates the phone was not picked up.

AND THEN show notification